# How do I use an Access Token with AWS SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have an App client created for a Cognito User Pool. The client has an ID and secret generated. It is configured to [use the Client credentials flow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-idp-settings.html) and has a custom scope defined. With that in place, I'm able to successfully exchange the creds for an Access Token, so far so good.

I would like to use AWS SDK to manage users (list, delete etc) in the User Pool with the server-side app client. Assuming I validated the granted token, how do I use it with AWS SDK to execute [Actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) I need? Is there a better way to manage User Pools from a server-side app?

Comment: What programming language are you using. TO be clear, are you asking once a user authenticates using Cognito, you want to know how to use the Congito SDK to perform supported actions?

Comment: I'm using Java/Scala, but should be able to understand an example in any language assuming that applying the issued token works similarly. I'm not authenticating with user credentials, but an app client ID and secret. Performing actions is meant to be done in a non-interactive, machine-to-machine manner.

Comment: Interesting concept. Only examples i know of is using OAuth and signing into an app by using user creds.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at **Admin*** level actions in the Cognito SDK (e.g. [AdminDeleteUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminDeleteUser.html)), you will see it does not accept access tokens. It rather expects valid AWS developer credentials.

So what you probably want to do is to create an IAM role with appropriate permissions to manage the user pool (resource format: `arn:aws:cognito-idp:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:userpool/USER_POOL_ID`) and let your server application assume that role. With correct permissions configured, you can call the AWS SDK directly.

You can find the list of available IAM actions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazoncognitouserpools.html).

Comment: Thanks Max, that would probably work, but it makes me wonder what's the purpose of the Client credentials flow. The doc says "use this flow when your app is requesting the token on its own behalf, not on behalf of a user. " [1] So the idea was to use the token to access the user pool for which the app client was created. I implemented something similar for other Id providers and it didn't require creating any special users or roles.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-idp-settings.html

Comment: @zaza I guess it makes sense in a scenario where you need to access protected resources as a machine user... One example that comes to mind is a backend API that provides some analytics. Cron script would authenticate with client credentials and request stats from that API and publish data to a Slack channel. The request will be authenticated either via Cognito Authorizer or by the API itself (by validating JWT in the code using one of the available libraries).